# Vulkan: update uniform variables without resetting command buffer

Tags: vulkan

As far as I know, when we update the uniform variables through "vkUpdateDescriptorSets", the status of the corresponding command buffer will be invalid. Accordingly, we have to reset the command buffer and re-record it.

Is there a way to update the uniform variables without doing anything to the command buffer?

What's the best way to update the data of uniform variables per frame (in the aspect of performance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Descriptors inside the descriptor sets refer to an area in a vkBuffer or vkImage.

You can safely update the contents of buffer or image between renders and keep the descriptors intact.

Make sure there are no read conflicts while the actual update takes place.

Comment: Thanks! I understood for the vkBuffer part, but I'm still confused about the image. Suppose I have two textures, 'A' and 'B' and I have prepared them at the beginning. How do I let the shader variable use 'A' in the first frame but change to 'B' in the second frame without calling "vkUpdateDescriptorSets" to change the vkImageView? Could you add more details about it?

Comment: in the second frame you will be rendering to a different swapchain image, so you need a different command buffer anyway. You can flip flop the texture (and very likely the vkbuffer) in sync with the swapchain image that way.